# C++0x: noexcept(ndebug) for testing?

Tags: testing, c++11, noexcept

I read about concern that the overly use of `noexcept` may hinder a testable library.

Consider:

```cpp
T& vector::front() noexcept {
    assert(!empty());         // <- this may throw in some test-frameworks
    return data[0];
}
```

With the annotation with `noexcept` the compiler may optimize exception-code out, which would/could prevent proper handling of `assert()` (or whichever function the author wants to use here for his tests).

Therefore, I wonder, if it is feasible in a library to **never use an unconditional `noexcept`** but to always "link" it with a am-I-in-a-test-condition. Like this:

```cpp
#ifdef NDEBUG    // asserts disabled
static constexpr bool ndebug = true;
#else            // asserts enabled
static constexpr bool ndebug = false;
#end

T& vector::front() noexcept(ndebug) {
    assert(!empty());
    return data[0];
}
```

and then maybe add it as a macro (although, I hate that):

```cpp
#define NOEXCEPT noexcept(ndebug)

T& vector::front() NOEXCEPT {
    assert(!empty());
    return data[0];
}
```

What do you think? Does this make any sense at all? Or is it not feasible? Or does it not solve the problem? Or is there no problem at all? :-)

Comment: I think you shouldn't have a testing environment that modifies the semantics of `assert`, which is after all part of the standard library.

Comment: It destroys one big advantage of having `noexcept` functions - that of having simple functions that can rely on called functions not throwing exceptions. With your flag, the functions can never be sure whether an exception is thrown, and will have to be written generally, possibly using the `noexcept` unary operator which adds compile time bloat and complexity into code (c.f. reallocation with `std::vector<T>` and its use of nothrow move constructors). I would just terminate my program with a backtrace on failed `assert` and be done with it.

Comment: @litb: No, it is not possible to "terminate() and be done with it". One paper describes that a unittest-suite will of course also do negative tests -- that `front()` on an empty `vector` must fail. This would not be possible it the program terminates. I can not follow your comment completely, though: what destroys what, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot prove that a function will not emit an exception then you should not tag it with `noexcept`. It's that simple.

That said, `noexcept(ndebug)` seems reasonable to me. I see no reason to hide it behind a macro. Template functions often have verbose `noexcept` conditions.

If the function within the asset can throw during test modes then your program can spontaneously `std::terminate` during test mode. (It's a lot like an implicit `assert` actually.)

The only downside I can see is that if this happens you won't get a line number and hint message. That, and the compiler ought to warn you if you call a `noexcept(false)` function from a `noexcept(true)` one, so you might get some noise.